# Angular: Is it possible to merge cells by columns?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to angular the following is the scenario: I spent 2 days for it.

Here my code:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%;"></td>
      <th style="width: 10%;">Date 2</th>
      <th style="width: 10%;">Date 3</th>
      <th style="width: 10%;">Date 4</th>
      <th style="width: 10%;">Date 5</th>
      <th style="width: 10%;">Date 6</th>
      <th style="width: 10%;">Date 7</th>
      <th style="width: 10%;">Date 8</th>
      <td style="width: 10%;"></td>
    </tr>

<div *ngFor="let itemdata of Data;">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of arrayOne(8); let i = index;">
        <td style="width: 10%;">row: {{i}}</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row {{i}} - col: 2</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row {{i}} - col: 3</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row {{i}} - col: 4</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row {{i}} - col: 5</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row {{i}} - col: 6</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row {{i}} - col: 7</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row {{i}} - col: 8</td>
        <td style="width: 10%;">row: {{i}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
</table>
```

**and data typescript in .ts is:**

```
Data: any[] = [
    {
      "maMH":"BT1",
      "nameMH":"Name 1",
      "date":3,
      "rowBegin":2,
      "merge":2,
    },
    {
      "maMH":"BT2",
      "nameMH":"Name 2",
      "date":5,
      "rowBegin":4,
      "merge":3,
    },
  ]
```

So, I cannot find out how to merge columns in html (with *ngFor="let itemdata of Data) (like in the example below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqgeh.png)

So is there some way of code, Thank.

[image]

Comment: `Data: any[]` are you using typescript or javascript?

Comment: oh, typescript!

Comment: Please explain a little more about what you're trying to achieve. You're saying you want to merge columns, yet the image you provided only shows certain cells in rows spanning over mutliple rows.

Comment: is mean I have data is: "day": 3, "rowBegin": 2, "merge": 2, How to merge cell and display in html (with *ngFor="let itemdata of Data") same my image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** I think you are looking for [rowspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp). But this has some drawbacks that any cells that exist where the rowspan is overspanning will be pushed to the next column.

You might want to look at a package for this, like [datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net). It has far more extensible functionalities than a standard HTML table. It looks like it supports rowspan and colspan: [datatables docs](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html)